# 30 Year old faucet cartridge replacement

Tags: bathroom, faucet, leaking

I have a leaky 2 handle bathroom faucet with the following cartridge below.

What brand is that cartridge/faucet (1st question), and is that so antiquated and old that I should replace the entire faucet (2nd question)? (*It does not look like a design I've worked with previously.*)

2nd question is more to, "oh no that's a terrible design and you shouldn't bother fixing that type of faucet," etc.. No need to effort replacing if this is not advisable.

[image]

Comment: What is the 2nd question, is it a True or False? (*i can not find my #2 pencil*)

Comment: You can get cartridges for prehistoric faucets.  I don't know what one you need but I've done that before.   Big mistake. $40 to $60 then you have ONE working rusty ugly tap.   It's not just the cartridge that's shot.  The finish on the once-glistening spout and handles is shot too.  If you even think gleaming gold taps are still good looking, this one isn't.  For about $150 you can replace the whole set, the popup, the TP holder, towel rail, and everything else with something that will give your bathroom a nice refresh and it will include ceramic cartridge taps, hot and cold, that work.

Comment: @jay613 - that's exactly what I ended up doing. The cartridges in my searches weren't standard, and ones like them are roughly $30 each. Not worth the investment for the facet which as you said looks worn. I don't like the gold either. Ended up getting a nice Pfister with white and chrome handles that match the toilet handle I already replaced. As you say much newer and refreshed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like a Price Pfister (or import copy thereof). Looks like a good quality faucet that is worth saving.

Note- you don't necessarily need to buy new "cartridges", these are totally rebuild-able unless physically damaged. The washers and o-rings should be readily available at a good hardware shop or plumbing shop (maybe not at big-box center). Waterproof grease and washers it will probably perform like new.

Look for Price Pfister widespread faucet parts. Bring the old because there are several configurations/types. If replacing stems/valves be aware that there are specific "left" and "right" because the levers move opposite of each other.